# How user can get latest copy from their protected branch(from my Org. Git repository) using gitlab4j-api?

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to connect a java program through my local organization git repository, and I am using gitlab4j-api open source API, I am able to login & get the project details from basic Java program. But which method can help me to do check out(individual user can get latest copy from their branch) process ?
Thanks

```
package git4j.git4j;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.gitlab4j.api.CommitsApi;
import org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi;
import org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiException;
import org.gitlab4j.api.ProjectApi;
import org.gitlab4j.api.models.Commit;
import org.gitlab4j.api.models.CommitAction;

import org.gitlab4j.api.models.Project;
import org.gitlab4j.api.models.CommitAction.Action;
import org.gitlab4j.api.models.CommitAction.Encoding;


public class App 
{
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main( String[] args )throws GitLabApiException
    {
      GitLabApi api = GitLabApi.login("http://organizationt_git.ad.com/", "username", "password");

    ProjectApi projApi=api.getProjectApi();
    Project p = projApi.getProject(project_id);

    System.out.println("project rendered is"+p.getName());
    List <Project> pList=projApi.getProjects("project_name");

           for(Project p:pList){                        

                                           System.out.println(p.getName());
                           }

                           CommitAction ca= new CommitAction();
                           Action a = Action.UPDATE;
                           ca.setAction(a); 
                           ca.setFilePath("c/");
                           ca.setPreviousPath("c/");
                           ca.setContent("test content");
                           ca.setEncoding(Encoding.TEXT);
                           ca.setLastCommitId("");
                           List<CommitAction> caList = new 
                           ArrayList<CommitAction>();
                           caList.add(ca);
                           CommitsApi cApi=api.getCommitsApi();
                           Commit c = cApi.createCommit(project_id,"branch", "commit message", "branch_refer_to", "", "username", caList);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about Gitlab or Github? please specify

Comment: Supposing that you 're referring to Gitlab API, is this even possible from the API itself without using any git operations?

Comment: I am talking about github or any git community which belongs to organization, using gitlab4j-api @VadimKotov

Comment: @BhageshArora I don't think you can use gitlab4j-api for things other than Gitlab. GitHub has it' own API and libraries.

Comment: @VadimKotov Please see the above program, I have used gitlab4j-api to connect my local org. git repository.

Comment: @BhageshArora I see. But this is not related to Github at all. It is just your local Gitlab instance.

Comment: @BhageshArora I mean this library is specific to Gitlab only (your local instance or gitlab.com, does not matter). But this is not applicable to Github.

Comment: @VadimKotov Yes, But we can use gitlab instance to connect my local repository, no need to connect from Github